# How do I get a script to find the player who activated a proximity prompt so I can use it to fire a remote event on that player?

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a proximity prompt on a part, so when you hold e it's supposed to make you're screen fade and teleport you, but I'm not sure why it's not fading the screen. Is it not finding the player?

This is what is supposed to tell the script to fire the "TeleportationDoorEvent" remote event and find the player to fire it on when they trigger the proximity prompt:

```lua
local ProximityPrompt = script.Parent
local TeleportationDoorEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.TeleportationDoorEvent

ProximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
        
    local plr = player.Character
    TeleportationDoorEvent:FireClient(plr)
            
end)
```

This is what makes their screen fade during teleportation:

```lua
local TeleportationDoorEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.TeleportationDoorEvent
local Frame = script.Parent.Frame

local TeleportTime = 1


TeleportationDoorEvent.OnClientEvent:Connect(function()
    for i = 1,10 do
        Frame.BackgroundTransparency -= 0.1
        wait(0.01)
    end
    wait(TeleportTime)
    for i = 1,10 do
        Frame.BackgroundTransparency += 0.1
        wait(0.01)
    end
end)
```

The TP script is working fine though. I need help, not sure why this won't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The proximity prompt gives you the player :

```lua
ProximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
    TeleportationDoorEvent:FireClient(player)
end)
```